# Can I replace a 2 Pole 24V/50A contactor with a 2 Pole 24V/40A one?

Tags: hvac, replacement, relay

I have an old Trane Executive AC [BTD736A100B0] unit that uses contactor-relay RLY03346.

I've seen plenty of 2 Pole 24V 40A contactors available, but the Trane RLY03346 contactor is actually a 2 Pole 24V 50A. Is it safe to drop down to a 40A contactor for this particular AC unit?

This Trane AC has always been very reliable, and the only issue I've had is the worn out relay sticking intermittently.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the circuit breaker size

Comment: What does the name plate on the compressor unit say as far as amperage?

Comment: If you need 50A, three pole ones might be cheaper, and you can ignore the third pole. The price on the Trane unit doesn't look out of line though compared to other similar sized contactors. You might want to just replace with OEM.

Comment: Okay, I just added an image of the name plate from the Trane unit. Is this helpful? Thanks for all the quick replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You should be able to use any 24V/40A definite purpose contactor

Unless the Trane contactor is pathologically weird, you should be able to find a replacement.  Based on NEC table 430.248, your compressor motor is considered between a 3HP and a 5HP motor based on its Rated Load Amps, so a typical 40A definite purpose contactor would have no trouble with it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I'll definitely go for a 2 Pole 24V 40A replacement then. I finally added pic of the compressor name plate, just for reference.

Comment: Btw, I just got a note from an admin saying this post/question was "off-topic" and that I needed to edit it, but provides no guidance on what part of it needs to be edited. Oh, well...

Comment: @TheBigCat yeah -- it was pretty borderline on being a "shop for me" question, hence the closure

Comment: ahhhh, okay i see now! I'll be mindful of that for future3 posts. Thanks!